# Software for Git in the enterprise?

Tags: git, github, gitorious, bitbucket-server, gitstack

We're looking at the prospect of using Git on our team, and hopefully get a lot of other dev teams to join us. If everything goes well I might be setting up Git for everyone. Currently I'm looking to test:

- [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/)
- [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/)
- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/)
- [Atlassian Stash](http://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview)
- [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/)

I'd love some thoughts on which ones are good, and if I've left out something I shouldn't.

I'm not quite sure what features we want and/or need, but we're mostly .NET and Java developers, Active Directory authentication is a must and JIRA integration would be sweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using JIRA, you should definitely take a look at Stash. It's built on the same platform and integrates with JIRA well. It also integrates with Active Directory out of the box.

Comment: This is what we went with, and we are very happy. (500 users)

Answer (score 5):

There is another solution, it's free and awesome, we use it as internal repository management

http://gitlabhq.com

On GitHub you can find out how to install it on your server:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki

For AD authentication, you must copy the config file config/initializers/omniauth.rb.sample to config/initializers/omniauth.rb, then edit it with your AD settings and finally restart gitlab.